# Not Getting Complete Output on Program in Eclipse

Tags: java, output

I am getting no errors from Eclipse but my console output is not what it should be. These are the 2 classes I am working on.

**First Class**

```java
public class BankAccount
{
    private double balance;    
    private double interestRate;
    private double interest;   

    public BankAccount(double startBalance, double intRate)
    {
        balance = startBalance;
        interestRate = intRate;
        interest = 0.0;
    }
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    public void addInterest()
    {
        interest = balance * interestRate;
        balance += interest;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public double getInterest()
    {
        return interest;
    }
}
```

**Next Class**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;    
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Program2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAccount account;

        double balance = 500,    
            interestRate = 0.00125, 
            pay = 1000,      
            cashNeeded = 900;  

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat ("#0.00");

        System.out.print("What is your account's starting balance?");
        balance = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("What is your monthly interest rate?");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        account = new BankAccount(balance, interestRate);

        System.out.print("How much were you paid this month? ");
        pay = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("We will deposit your pay into your account.");
        account.deposit(pay);
        System.out.println("Your current balance is " 
            + formatter.format(account.getBalance()));

        System.out.print("How much would you like to withdraw? ");
        cashNeeded = keyboard.nextDouble();
        account.withdraw(cashNeeded);

        account.getInterest();
        System.out.println("This month you have earned " 
            + formatter.format( account.getInterest() ) 
            + " in interest.");

        System.out.println("Now your balance is " 
            + formatter.format( account.getBalance()));
    }
}
```

**Output which I am Getting:**

> What is your account's starting balance?

**Output I should be getting:**

> What is your account's starting balance? 500
>   What is your monthly interest rate? 0.00125
>   How much were you paid this month? 1000
>   We will deposit your pay into your account.
>   Your current balance is 1500.00
>   How much would you like to withdraw? 900
>  
>   This month you have earned 0.75 in interest.
>   Now your balance is 600.75

Comment: Are you giving it the input it's asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Scanners wait for input, until you give it information, it won't move on.

Answer (score 0):

It is working totally fine.
I haven't modified anything in your code.
Actually I am thinking when the program is asking you to enter something, at that point you are not giving the input.

Try giving the input for example 500 when it asks **`What is your account's starting balance?`**